# Can we use Visualbasic.PowerPacks.Vs with ASP.NET Core to sent text to printer?

Tags: asp.net-core, printing

I have a windows application which uses Visualbasic.PowerPacks.Vs for printing text. Can we use the same in ASP.NET Core WebAPI? When I tried to use it, its not giving any error but showing a yellow explanation symbol next to Dependencies node in solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks namespace contains classes for the Visual Basic Power Packs controls. Visual Basic Power Packs controls are additional Windows Forms controls. So we don't suggest you use this control in asp.net core. Since asp.net core web api is a server project and the user couldn't see the server's Win form controls.

If you want to print something, I suggest you could consider using [System.Drawing Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#methods). You will need to write code in order to draw your shapes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
We are using label printing in our application and old application uses VisualBasic.Powerapacks but with new ASP.NET Core application looks like we need to use something similar to   https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-mvc/.
Any ideas if we have something open source for Label printing?

Comment: Could you please tell me your requirement when you want to use this Label printing?

Comment: We want to print labels sending print command to the printer with specific format.